# C code for storing sqlite db does not store data in physical memory

Tags: c, sqlite

Although this program works perfectly during execution on my dev-C++ compiler,taking in values and displaying it again, the next time it is executed it does not open the previous databases and i have to enter the data again.The db data entered is not being stored physically in memory.Please help!

```
void fill(sqlite3* db, char* tbname);
void CreateDatabase(sqlite3** db);
void CreateTable(sqlite3* db, char* tbname);
void display(sqlite3* db, char* tbname);

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s = ",azColName[i]);
        if( argv[i] )
            printf(argv[i]);
        else
            printf("NULL");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void dsperr(char**db_err)
{
    if( *db_err )
    {
        printf("db_err\n");
        sqlite3_free(*db_err); // release (free) memory
        *db_err = 0; // reinitialize the caller's pointer
    }
}

void GetTablename(char* tbname)
{
    printf("Enter the table name\n");
    scanf("%s", tbname);
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sqlite3* db = 0; // database connection
        char tbname[DBNAMESIZE];   // table name
        int done = 0;
        while(!done)
        {
            char answer[8] = {0};
            printf("\n\nPlease select one of the folowing options\n");
            printf("1. Create a new or open an existing database\n");
            printf("2. Create a new table\n");
            printf("3. Add some data\n");
            printf("4. List all data\n");
            printf("5. Quit\n");
            scanf("%1s",answer);

            switch(answer[0])
            {
            case '1':
                CreateDatabase(&db);
                break;
            case '2':
                CreateTable(db, tbname);
                break;
            case '3':
                fill(db, tbname);
                break;
            case '4':
                display(db, tbname);
                break;
            case '5':
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}

void CreateDatabase(sqlite3** db)
{
    char dbname[DBNAMESIZE];
    int n;
    printf("Please enter the name of the database\n");
    scanf("%s",dbname);
    fgets(dbname,sizeof(dbname), stdin);

    if( dbname[strlen(dbname)-1] == '\n')
        dbname[strlen(dbname)-1] = '\0';
    n = sqlite3_open(dbname, db);
    if( n != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        printf("Error opening database.\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Database open ok\n");
}

void CreateTable(sqlite3* db, char* tbname)
{
    char* db_err = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char statement[255] = {0};
    GetTablename(tbname);

    if( tbname[0] == '\0' )
        return;
    sprintf(statement, "CREATE TABLE %s (id integer);", tbname);

    n = sqlite3_exec(db, statement, NULL, 0, &db_err);
    dsperr(&db_err);
    if( n != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        printf("Error executing \"%s\"\n",statement);
    }
    else
        printf("Table created successfully\n");
}

void fill(sqlite3* db, char* tbname)
{
    char* db_err = 0;
    int id;
    int n = 0;
    char buf[80];

    if( strlen(tbname) == 0)
    {
        GetTablename(tbname);
        if( tbname[0] == '\0')
            return;
    }

    printf("Enter the data into the table\n");
    scanf("%d",&id);
    sprintf(buf,"insert into %s values(%d);", tbname, id);
    n = sqlite3_exec(db, buf, NULL, 0, &db_err);
    dsperr(&db_err);

    if( n != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        printf("Error inserting value %d\n", id);
        return;
    }
}

void display(sqlite3* db, char* tbname)
{
    char* db_err = 0;
    char select[255] = {0};
    if( strlen(tbname) == 0)
    {
        GetTablename(tbname);
        if( tbname[0] == '\0' )
            return;
    }

    if( strlen(tbname) > 0)
    {
        sprintf(select, "select * from %s;", tbname);
        sqlite3_exec(db, select, callback, 0, &db_err);
        dsperr(&db_err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used C in years but according to documentation for `sqlite3_open()` on [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html):

> If the filename is an empty string, then a private, temporary on-disk database will be created. This private database will be automatically deleted as soon as the database connection is closed.

Possibly you're passing an empty string to `sqlite3_open()`? It looks like you're reading `dbname` twice, once with `scanf` and once with `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `dbname` is not filled correctly in `createdatabase`. Removing `fgets(...)` below `scanf(..)` at least *generates* a database file named correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have used

```
fgets(dbname,sizeof(dbname), stdin);
```

but it clears the dbname string, and creates a temporary database.
if you remove this line it will create the database as it should.

Also the outer while loop in main is not necessary, and doesn't allow the user to quit.

Comment: I used fgets initially to get the name of the db..didnt know it would cause such a big problem! and yes i now removed that outer while loop,thanks Jan!!